# How can I rename a lot of files using a regex?

Tags: files, rename

I want to rename a lot of files on Mac OS X (10.7.2).. I don't have the perl package for the `rename` command.

My files have names like "T452-102456-0.png" and I want to delete the "-0" part. I know I can do this action by writing my own php-cli script, but I would like to know of an easier and faster solution.

Comment: Isn't there logical contradiction between “a lot of pdf files” and “My files have names like "T452-102456-0.png"”?

Comment: Oh... the type of files doesn't matter, but it's true ^^. I edit, thank you for your comment =)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Bash or Ksh together with `mv` could solve it:

```sh
for f in *.png; do mv -n "$f" "${f/-0}"; done
```

In case the file name may have “0” after the first dash too and the “-0” is always in front of the dot, you may want to include that dot too in the expression:

```sh
for f in *.png; do mv -n "$f" "${f/-0./.}"; done
```

But as that renaming rule is simple, if you have `rename` from the *util-linux* package, that will do it too:

```sh
rename '-0.' '.' *.png
```

Comment: it works perfectly. Thank you very much =)

Answer (score 5):

**Simple method: Files in current directory only**

With zsh:

```
autoload zmv
zmv '(*)-0(.png)' '$1$2'
```

With other shells:

```
for x in *-0.png; do mv -- "$x" "${x%-0.*}.png"; done
```

**Enhanced method: Files in current directory and/or subdirectories**

With zsh:

```
zmv '(**/)(*)-0(.png)' '$1$2$3'
```

With ksh93:

```
set -o globstar
for x in **/*-0.png; do mv -- "$x" "${x%-0.*}.png"; done
```

With bash ≥4, as above, but use `shopt -s globstar` instead of the `set` command.

With other shells:

```
find -name '*-0.png' -exec sh -c 'for x; do mv -- "$x" "${x%-0.*}.png"; done' _ {} +
```

Comment: another great reason to install zsh :)....zmv

Comment: zmv!!! cool! thanks.

Comment: `autoload zmv` was helpful! And needed before it will work. 

Tip for others: add `autoload zmv` to your .zshrc file so you don't need to type it each time and learn about useful zmv options by running `zmv` with no parameters.

Answer (score 3):

In Fish Shell on OSX:

```
for f in *.png; mv -n $f (basename $f -0.png).png; end
```

Fish Shell: https://fishshell.com/

Comment: And downvote for what reason? This is a valid answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `mmv` package:

```
mmv '*-0.png' '#1.png'
```

Like (recent versions of) `rename`, this will take reasonable care to avoid overwriting existing files.