# How do I rename multiple files

Tags: rhel, rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I rename a lot of files using a regex?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24107/how-can-i-rename-a-lot-of-files-using-a-regex)

I've got some files named

```
abc-10.5.3.1-1.x86_64.rpm
abc-compiler-10.5.3.1-1.x86_64.rpm
abc-10.5.3.1-6.x86_64.rpm   
abc-compiler-10.5.3.1-6.x86_64.rpm
```

I'd like to remove the minor version numbers (1-1 and 1-6) whenver the files are built. I can't figure out how to achieve this with the rename command on Redhat linux. The resulting filename should for example be:

```
abc-10.5.3.x86_64.rpm
```

The command doesn't take regular expressions.

Comment: The regexp version of rename is a fairly short perl script. I found a [copy of the Debian one on Github](https://raw.github.com/gist/883553/01bb2c924a5724ea2b6804886c1a54329473fefa/prename.pl)

Comment: Be careful about removing the minor version. Even the build number (the part between last dash and `.<arch>` specifier) can have significance in some cases, but removing part of version number is usually not really a good idea - the version number is there for some reason. :)

Comment: @peterph The renamed files are for internal use and not to be distributed

Comment: @kalengi some distributions strip the version numbers from the filenames completely. It's just that you can mess up easily by mixing various patch levels, e.g. by not noticing during a copy/move operation, that only some of the packages got overwritten and end up with mismatching `abc` and `abc-compiler` packages. Which on install might be caught by `rpm`, but on extra cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to consider alternatives to `rename`, with zsh, I'd write:

```
autoload -U zmv
zmv -n '(*).<->-<->(.[^.]##.rpm)' '$1$2'
```

(and remove `-n` when happy).

Comment: This is a very elegant solution :)

Answer (score 2):

If your `rename(1)` is anything like [this Fedora one](http://linuxmanpages.net/manpages/fedora17/man1/rename.1.html) I don't think it will work for what you want to do.

Here is one approach which requires `bash`:

```
( shopt -s extglob
for f in ./*-+([.[:digit:]])-+([[:digit:]]).x86_64.rpm; do
    mv -v -- "$f" "${f%-+([[:digit:]]).x86_64.rpm)}.x86_64.rpm"
done )
```

The `+([.[:digit:]])` part is to match the major/minor version number, and the `+([[:digit:]])` after the `-` is to match the patch number which you are trying to remove.

You could also do something less accurate with POSIX `sh`, which lacks `extglob`

```
for f in ./*-*-*.x86_64.rpm; do
    mv -v -- "$f" "${f%-*.x86_64.rpm}.x86_64.rpm"
done
```