# Rename multiples files using Bash scripting

Tags: bash, rename

I want to rename multiple files in the same directory using Bash scripting. Names of the files are as follows:

```
file2602201409853.p
file0901201437404.p  
file0901201438761.p  
file1003201410069.p  
file2602201410180.p
```

I want to rename to the following format:

```
file2503201409853.p
file2503201437404.p  
file2503201438761.p  
file2503201410069.p  
file2503201410180.p
```

I was reading about the rename command, and try to do it this way, but it does nothing, I think I have questions about the syntax. Then I read that you can make a loop using the [mv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mv) command as follows:

```
for file in cmpsms*2014*.p; do
    mv "$file" "${file/cmpsms*2014*.p/cmpsms25032014*.p}"
done
```

But I can not rename the files. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I rename a lot of files using a regex?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24107/how-can-i-rename-a-lot-of-files-using-a-regex)

Comment: You can't have a pattern expression on the right hand side of a parameter expansion replacement expression. What did you expect to be where that `*` is?

Comment: @Kiwy That question is about removing a portion of the file name. Ergo, highly doubtfully duplicate.

Comment: Next time, please describe the file name changes you want to make (I had to look at this for a fair while before seeing the differences and similarities). Examples are good, but a description *as well as* examples is even better.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You were right to consider rename first. The syntax is a little strange if you're not used to regexes but it's by far the quickest/shortest route once you know what you're doing:

```
rename 's/\d{4}/2503/' file*
```

That simply matches the first 4 numbers and swaps them for the ones you specified.

And a test harness (`-vn` means be verbose but don't *do* anything) using your filenames:

```
$ rename 's/\d{4}/2503/' file* -vn
file0901201437404.p renamed as file2503201437404.p
file0901201438761.p renamed as file2503201438761.p
file1003201410069.p renamed as file2503201410069.p
file2602201409853.p renamed as file2503201409853.p
file2602201410180.p renamed as file2503201410180.p
```

Comment: Note that this is the Perl rename on Debian and derivatives (Ubuntu, Mint, …). On other Linux distributions, `rename` is a completely different file renaming tool (which Debian ships as `rename.ul`).

Comment: If your distributive lack of such tool, look at @Michael Campbell answer. I think every distributive replace default `rename` like debian did.

Answer (score 25):

This should do the trick:

```
for f in file*; do mv $f ${f/${f:4:8}/25032014}; done
```

It replaces the string beween the 4th and the 12th character with "25032014".

Comment: this `for f in file*; do mv $f ${f/${f:4:4}/2503}; done` also work.

Comment: That's nice.  If you just want to do a regular word for word replacement, it works like sed.            e.g. `for f in *Huge*; do mv $f ${f/Huge/Monstrous}; done`

Comment: @Eric - I posted your answer as an alternative because I think it's more clear and elegant.  If you also want to post it as an answer - I'll delete mine.  Thanks!

Comment: Why the [missing double quotes](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)?

Comment: It gives me an error: "mv: target 'FILE_NAME' is not a directory"

Answer (score 11):

this is really @Eric's answer from above - but it's an elegant answer so I'm reposting it as a proper answer to draw more attention to it.

```
for f in *Huge*; do mv "$f" "${f/Huge/Monstrous}"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ptrn='file[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]2014[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].p'
path=/dir
( set -- "${path}/"${ptrn} ; for f ; do {
    echo "mv ${path}/${f} \
        ${path}/file25032014${f#2014}" 
} ; done )
```

This should do the trick. Note - I'm not in the habit of handing over mass mv commands - as written it's just an echo. You'll have to sort that out before it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

A simple native way to do it without looping, with **directory traversal**:

```
find -type f | xargs -I {} mv {} {}.txt
```

It will rename every file in place.

And below a working example with **parallelization**:

```
find -name "file*.p" | parallel 'f="{}" ; mv -- {} ${f:0:4}2503${f:8}'
```

Comment: It was a  easy first approach to imagine better solution. If you want a working command  do:

Comment: `find -type f -name "file*.p" | parallel 'ext="{}" ; mv -- {} ${ext:0:4}2503${ext:8}'`

Answer (score 0):

If you find you do this sort of thing a lot, look up "rename.pl".  It's a perl script, but allows you to simply feed it perl code (like a s/// expression), and it will do a mass rename based on that expression or code.

There's a basic version here: http://stackoverflow.org/wiki/Rename.pl  but there are other versions floating around the net.  It's been around for ages and ages and ages.