# What does mv do when changing names?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rename, mv

I have a very peculiar problem, following an answer in [Rename multiples files using Bash scripting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121570/rename-multiples-files-using-bash-scripting) I am trying to rename some files. This is the code I am using

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.HHZ_00; do mv $file ${file/${file:14:2}/00}; done
```

What I understand this to do is to replace the 2 characters following character index 14 (starting from zero) to 00.

I am using 2 subsets of files to test it, one is this

```
2018113154211.25.AGCC.HHZ_00
2018113154211.25.APAC.HHZ_00
```

When running the code these successfully rename to

```
2018113154211.00.AGCC.HHZ_00
2018113154211.00.APAC.HHZ_00
```

The second subset fails at this, this subset is

```
2018070220829.28.AGCC.HHZ_00
2018070220829.29.APAC.HHZ_00
```

These rename unsuccessfully to

```
2018070220829.00.AGCC.HHZ_00
2018070220800.29.APAC.HHZ_00
```

Notice how the indices 11 and 12 are changed for the second file, not the 14 and 15 as I want it to, very curiously now the SECOND time I run it, using the last files as input, I get

```
2018070220829.00.AGCC.HHZ_00
2018070220800.00.APAC.HHZ_00
```

This is partially successful, but now the second filename is ruined...what am I doing wrong? Is it because the 29 is repeating in these files?

If someone has a solution using the rename command that would be great too, I tried using it but I am unfamiliar with the syntax.

Comment: Yes it's because the characters repeat; `${file/${file:14:2}/00}` replaces the *first* instance of whatever characters occur in positions 14-15

Comment: ... you could simply use `"${file:0:14}00${file:16}"` I think?

Comment: You might find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809666/rename-files-using-regular-expression-in-linux helpful if you're comfortable with regex

Comment: @steeldriver  That's an answer in the comments. Let's turn it into a proper answer  instead of just comment

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy good point, converted to answer below

Comment: The `${…}` substitution is done by the shell. It has nothing to do with `mv`. First work out what you want to tell `mv` to do. Then workout how to tell the shell, to tell `mv` to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's because the characters repeat; `${file/${file:14:2}/00}` replaces the *first* instance of whatever characters occur in positions 14-15.

A simple way to do it in bash, without the nested parameter expansion, would be

```
$ for file in *.HHZ_00; do 
    echo mv "$file" "${file:0:14}00${file:16}"
  done
mv 2018070220829.28.AGCC.HHZ_00 2018070220829.00.AGCC.HHZ_00
mv 2018070220829.29.APAC.HHZ_00 2018070220829.00.APAC.HHZ_00
mv 2018113154211.25.AGCC.HHZ_00 2018113154211.00.AGCC.HHZ_00
mv 2018113154211.25.APAC.HHZ_00 2018113154211.00.APAC.HHZ_00
```

POSIXly, you could use `%%` and `#` (twice) to remove the longest suffix and shortest prefix respectively:

```
$ for file in *.HHZ_00; do 
    pfx="${file%%.*}"; rem="${file#*.}"; sfx="${rem#*.}" 
    echo mv "$file" "${pfx}.00.${sfx}"
  done
mv 2018070220829.28.AGCC.HHZ_00 2018070220829.00.AGCC.HHZ_00
mv 2018070220829.29.APAC.HHZ_00 2018070220829.00.APAC.HHZ_00
mv 2018113154211.25.AGCC.HHZ_00 2018113154211.00.AGCC.HHZ_00
mv 2018113154211.25.APAC.HHZ_00 2018113154211.00.APAC.HHZ_00
```

Remove the `echo` once you are satisfied that it is doing the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

@steeldriver explained it wonderfully, I corrected this by using

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.HHZ_00; do mv $file ${file/${file:13:4}/.00.}; done
```