# sed /PATTERN/SUB/ $VAR?

Tags: bash, sed, variable-substitution

I am renaming some files.

This works:
    `ls | while IFS= read -r line; do name=$(echo $line | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\1.jpg/') && mv $line $name; done`

Which is okay but I'd like to make it more concise, like:
    `ls | while IFS= read -r line; do name=$(sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\1.jpg/' $line) && mv $line $name; done`

The latter example and various similar attempts pass the file into sed rather than the value of the variable.

Using ˋ`$line`ˋ and `$($line)` both result in an attempt to execute the file.  While variations of `"$line"`, `'line'` with and without `<`, all lead to the file be read in.  What is going on here?  Can the `$line` variable be used directly with sed for this purpose?

Comment: You can use a *here string* `<<< "$line"` - however, you should really rethink your entire approach. Do you really need anything more than `for f in *; do mv -- "$f" "$f.jpg"; done`?

Comment: Are you attempting to append ".jpg" to every existing filename?  Or replace the current extension with ".jpg"?  Either way, there are much simpler ways to go about it - see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24107/how-can-i-rename-a-lot-of-files-using-a-regex

Comment: How can conciseness be worth anything with such an ugly command (in both cases)?  Who cares if their command is 4 bytes longer, especially if it can be written in a script?

Comment: There are two reasons for this question, 1. I've learned something; 2. In my opinion `<<< "$line"` is more readable than `echo $line | sed`.

Comment: `prename 's/$/.jpg/' * `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *Here String* with `<<<` syntax:

```
ls | while IFS= read -r line
do
  name=$(sed 's/\(.*\)/\1.jpg/' <<< $line) && mv "$line" "$name"
done
```

Be aware that it's not considered a good idea to parse the output of `ls` (nor to use unquoted variables).

There is also a tool name `rename` (in case goal is simply to rename file):

```
rename -n 's/$/.jpg/' *
```

Remove the `-n` flag to change from preview to actual renaming.

Comment: My example above is a part of larger script which has a more complex sed pattern.

Also, the use of the ls just for this example for ease of use etc.

Comment: Note that that loop approach still fails if there are file names that start with `-` or contain newline characters or sequences of bytes not forming valid characters. See [@Kusalananda's answer](/a/336349) for a more correct approach.

Answer (score 7):

It *looks like* you're just wanting to append `.jpg` to the end of all the names of the files in the current directory.  If that's the case, then there are easier ways:

```
for f in ./*; do
  mv -- "$f" "$f.jpg"
done
```

The `--` makes sure that filenames with an initial dash (`-`) are not interpreted as options for `mv`. This is not an issue here though as we're also making sure that `$f` always has the path `./` in the beginning through using `./*` in the loop.

The output from `ls` is for reading by eyes, and is not generally suitable for sending into a while-read-loop like you're doing.

And yes, in your second example (`sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\1.jpg/' $line`), the contents of the file will be read by `sed`.  With Bash, you could do `sed '...' <<<"$line"` instead.  The `<<<"string"` construct is a Bash extension (also available in at least `ksh` and `zsh`) and is called "here-string", and it will pass the string on standard input to the command.